# A Philadelphia Question

Tags: pronouns, pennsylvanian-english

Up until recently I was firmly convinced that the expression "youse guys" originally came from Brooklyn, New York. A couple of days ago I ran across an essay that mentioned (in a disgustingly nonchalant manner) that it's been in active use in Philadelphia since before the Pilgrims. Last night I watched an episode of a slow and muddled British series in which it was suggested that it was popular among 19th Century guttersnipes in London. Now I'm confused.

Please ... uh ... elucidate.

Comment: Certainly there's a lot in common between the classical Philly accent and the Joisey accent commonly depicted in Brooklynites (whether accurately or not, I don't know).  But keep in mind that what may sound similar to the unfamiliar ear may be quite distinctive to a native.

Comment: @Hot Licks: the earliest citation  OED has for *yous/youse* is from Dublin  in 1835. And I wouldn't be surprised if some of the 19th century guttersnipes in London were Irish. The first instances of *yous(e) guys* in Google books are from the end of the 19th century, and seem to be American.

Comment: So it's actually .... uh ... Celtic?! ... Wow.

Comment: @PeterShor - But there's a lot more to an accent than "youse".

Comment: @Hot Licks: I never said there wasn't. I actually intended that comment to be general, not specifically addressed to you. Sorry. (What I meant to say to you in a comment was that the Philly and "Brooklyn" accents have a lot in common, but are recognizably different.)

Comment: @PeterShor You are correct that the accents share many features, like extreme resistance to the Mary-marry-merry merger. And the movies would also have us believe that the dialects are similar (*e.g.*, Rocky spoke with a Brooklyn accent). But [the Mid-Atlantic Dialect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mid-Atlantic_American_English), which is what's spoken in Philly, is actually quite distinct. For example, it has extreme fronting (followed by gliding) of the vowels, which does not occur in the NYC accent.  For example, [check out this video series](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yq9NBJ0sG48).

Comment: @ESultanik: Philadelphia shares some features of NYC English that most of the mid-Atlantic region doesn't share, and qualifies as its own unique dialect region. At least according to [this webpage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Philadelphia_English). For example, *dog* and *coffee* are diphthongized in Philly and NYC, but not in Baltimore. I don't know whether *youse guys* is found in Baltimore, but it certainly is in Philadelphia and NYC, which is what started this whole discussion.

Comment: @ESultanik: And [this map](https://www4.uwm.edu/FLL/linguistics/dialect/staticmaps/q_50.html) seems to indicate that *youse* is not common in Baltimore.

Comment: http://www.betootaadvocate.com/uncategorized/nrl-allocates-2m-to-help-stop-players-from-saying-youse/

Answer (score 1):

I just read a book called Speaking American.  I ran across that term which it attributed to NE Pennsylvania; cannot recall if it also included Philly.

Comment: Was it this book: [*Speaking American: How Y'all, Youse, and You Guys Talk: A Visual Guide*](https://books.google.com.au/books?id=a0hQDQAAQBAJ&dq=%22speaking+american%22+youse&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y)?

Comment: Philly is not in NE Pennsylvania.

Comment: Agreed, however it is a mere two hour drive from it.  I would imagine there are some NEPA transplants there.

Comment: Yes, Lawrence, that is the book.  I found it fun and interesting.  I've traveled much of the country so was personally familiar with many of its findings.

Comment: @Cali - Not during rush hour.

Comment: Indeed.  I had a Saturday night flight out of Philly.  The traffic was breathtaking.  Needless to say I missed the flight and the next one out of BWI and the next one out of Washington National.  I agree.  Rush hour + Philly = not a good situation.